# Library/Database of parametric polynomial systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, groebner-bases, resultants, elimination-theory

Could anyone please recommend a known website where I can find a database/library that has systems of polynomial equations with $n$ variables and  $m$ parameters?

I need some real examples to test my elimination algorithm.

Systems with more variables than equations will also do.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [database of polynomial systems](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ejan/demo.html), which comes with [PHCpack](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ejan/PHCpack/phcpack.html) by Jan Verschelde.